# Arabic language not displaying in Notepad

Tags: html

peace upon you

I have a problem with the language when I was in the notepad

An idea about the subject

I tried to put metadata `utf-8`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

It doesn't show the arabic words, it shows question marks instead

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Include the two tags inside your paragraph marker:

- dir="rtl"
- lang="ar"

  رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا

`<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</p>`

Answer (score -1):

Here the meta tag you can use if you are using notepad.

```
**<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>**
```

if you are using modern text editor like sublime you don't need to put that.